# Recursive printing of file directory in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to figure out how to print out each item in a directory with proper indentation. The code I have so far is below:

```
import os

def traverse(pathname,d):
    'prints a given nested directory with proper indentation'
    indent = ''
    for i in range(d):
        indent = indent + '  '
    for item in os.listdir(pathname):
        try:
            newItem = os.path.join(pathname, item)
            traverse(newItem,d+1)
        except:
            print(indent + newItem)
```

The output that I have prints out all the files in the test directory, but does not print out the folder names. What I get is this:

```
>>> traverse('test',0)
test/fileA.txt
  test/folder1/fileB.txt
  test/folder1/fileC.txt
    test/folder1/folder11/fileD.txt
  test/folder2/fileD.txt
  test/folder2/fileE.txt
>>>
```

What the output should be:

```
>>> traverse('test',0)
test/fileA.txt
test/folder1
  test/folder1/fileB.txt
  test/folder1/fileC.txt
  test/folder1/folder11
    test/folder1/folder11/fileD.txt
test/folder2
  test/folder2/fileD.txt
  test/folder2/fileE.txt
>>>
```

Can anyone let me know what I need to be doing with the code to get the folder names to show up? I've tried to print out the pathname, but it just repeats the folder name every time Python prints out a file name since it is in a for loop. A nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a problem in which I can really only use os.path and os.listdir. I would like to use other methods, but I think I'm supposed to create a function without the use of other os methods.

Comment: You can still print the pathname in the first for loop, but do some truncating to get the full file path to look like the folder location.

Comment: I've said it before, and I'll say it again - forcing someone to avoid built in functionality in a language is counterproductive.  If the _only_ way a professor can come up with to teach recursion is by walking directories they're doing damage.  Use what the language provides, teach concepts in better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print the file name whether it's a directory or not, something like:

```
for item in os.listdir(pathname):
    try:
        newItem = os.path.join(pathname, item)
        print(indent + newItem)
        traverse(newItem,d+1)
    except:
        pass
```

Though I would rather not use an exception to detect whether it's a directory, so if `os.path.isdir` is allowed:

```
for item in os.listdir(pathname):
    newItem = os.path.join(pathname, item)
    print(indent + newItem)
    if (os.path.isdir(newItem)):
        traverse(newItem,d+1)
```

Comment: Ohhh...you are quite correct. That was dumb of me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A recursive directory printing function that does *not* use `os.walk` might look something like this:

```
def traverse(root, depth, indent=''):
  for file_ in os.listdir(root):
    leaf = os.path.join(root, file_)
    print indent, leaf
    if os.path.isdir(leaf) and depth:
      traverse(leaf, depth-1, indent + '  ')
```

I don't approve of teaching people to avoid built ins to try to drive home a concept.  There are plenty of ways to teach recursion without making someone neglect the finer aspects of the language they're learning.  That's my opinion though, and apparently not one shared by many professors.

Comment: I can see your point of view. I do think teaching a programming language means exploration and trial and error rather than limiting us.